# Variable in partial reference

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm trying to load the partial `content/{{ page }}.hbs`, where `page` is a variable sent to the template in node. Despite the partial file existing, I get the following error when trying to load using `{{> content/{{ page }} }}`:

```
Expecting 'ID', got 'OPEN'
```

Loading `content/home.hbs` however, for example, works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be called "dynamic partial" – you can check [here](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html) in Handlebars docs.

> It's possible to dynamically select the partial to be executed by
>   using sub expression syntax. `{{> (whichPartial) }}` Will evaluate
>   whichPartial and then render the partial whose name is returned by
>   this function. Subexpressions do not resolve variables so whichPartial
>   must be a function. If a simple variable has the partial name, it's
>   possible to resolve it via the lookup helper. 
>   `{{> (lookup . 'myVariable') }}`